# Не могу, написать программу, которая анализирует слово на определенную букву

Tags: python

При использовании модуля re я не могу сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог вводить нужное ему слово. То есть, без второй строки все работает корректно, но тогда нужное слово можно ввести только через код

```
import re
y=str(input("Введите слово:"))
txt = "(y)"
x = re.search("^[Фф]+$", txt)
if x:
  print("YES! We have a match!")
else:
  print("No match")
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение данной задачи, все проверил, работает

```
import re
y=str(input("Введите слово:"))
x = re.search("^ф", y)
if x:
  print("Ого! Вы ввели редкое слово!")
else:
  print("Эх, это не очень редкое слово...")
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял логику, то можно так:

```
import re
y=input("Введите слово:") # str() здесь не нужен, т.к. input() всегда возвращает строку
x = re.search(r"^[Фф]\w+$", y) # текст должен состоять из 1 слова не менее чем из 2-х букв и начинаться на `Ф` в любом регистре
if x:
  print("YES! We have a match!")
else:
  print("No match")
```

```
Введите слово:Футбол
YES! We have a match!
```

Регулярно